# How to resolve error TS2307 in AWS CodeBuild when using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, deployment, codebuild

I've set up a pipeline to deploy a NodeJS (TypeScript) application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However, I'm encountering TS2307 errors during the compilation stage in CodeBuild. The build runs successfully in my local environment (MacOS) without any issues. Below is the error output and my buildspec.yml and tsconfig.json configurations. Any insights into resolving this AWS CodeBuild issue would be appreciated.

Error Output:

```
[Container] 2023/12/21 21:25:39.535669 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/12/21 21:25:39.535686 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/12/21 21:25:39.565655 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2023/12/21 21:25:39.566318 Running command tsc
src/modules/User/services.ts(15,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../mail/services' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/User/services.ts(16,72): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../mail/templates' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/User/services.ts(17,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../wallet/services' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/auth/services.ts(6,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../authCode/services' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/auth/services.ts(7,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../mail/services' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/auth/services.ts(8,81): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../mail/templates' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/auth/services.ts(9,44): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../user/services' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/auth/services.ts(10,41): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../authCode/services' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/quotation/services.ts(2,46): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../splitRisk/services' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/quotation/services.ts(4,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../pricing/services' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/modules/quotation/types.ts(2,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../vehicle/types' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/routes.ts(6,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module './modules/coupons/routes' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/routes.ts(7,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './modules/fipe/routes' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/routes.ts(8,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module './modules/pricingRules/routes' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/routes.ts(10,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './modules/user/routes' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/routes.ts(11,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module './modules/vehicle/routes' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/types/request.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../modules/user/types' or its corresponding type declarations.

[Container] 2023/12/21 21:25:44.189969 Command did not exit successfully tsc exit status 2
[Container] 2023/12/21 21:25:44.195064 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/12/21 21:25:44.195079 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: tsc. Reason: exit status 2
```

buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: latest
    commands:
      - npm install -g typescript
      - npm install
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pwd
      - npm ci --no-cache
  build:
    commands:
      - tsc

artifacts:
  files:
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - 'build/**/*'
  discard-paths: yes
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

I have already tried running the build locally, and it was successful. What could be causing these TS2307 errors specifically in the AWS CodeBuild environment?"